# Force one column to content, the other column to rest of size

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I have a layout like in the following fiddle:

```
<div>
    <span style="float:left;">This is a longer text that could potentially split into more than one line.</span>
    <span style="float:right;">Force this text into one line.</span>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pE2c8/).

What I am trying to accomplish is that the right span adjusts size so it's as small as possible but fits its content in one line. The left span should adjust to the rest of the main div size and can break text into as many lines as needed.

Restrictions:

- Content is variable for both spans. The left one is potentially unlimited, the right one will never take more than about 30% of the screen.
- I would really like a pure css/html solution. With Javascript I know how to do it, but it would make it harder to mantain, thus I am exploring something cleaner.
- First line of the left span should always be on the same line as the first line of the right one.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the content dynamic ?

Comment: Yes it is, that's the issue, I cannot fix widths. And I cannot use Javascript to adjust it afterwards as the div is updated with AJAX and it's quite messy to handle the event (other technical issues). Besides, I would really like a clean html approach (if it exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method #1

If you don't want to specify an explicit `width`, you can use `display: table;` for the `left` span:

```css
.left {
    display: table;
    background-color: orange; /*Just for demo */
}

.right {
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: gold; /*Just for demo */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/pE2c8/8/)**.

### Method #2

Also, you can display the left `span` as a block level element and hide the horizontal overflow by [`overflow-x: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) as follows:

```css
.left {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/pE2c8/10/)**.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the behaviour I was looking for and it does the trick. It only fails if the right span does not allow space for the first word in the left one, which is 100% understandable and will do just fine as I am sure my right span will never go over about 30%...

Comment: Just one more comment. I finally used your approach, but I had to fix widths. Inside the page, the left object was aquiring arbitrary sizes, specially on IE, but the layout really helped me to get to a simpler rule to fix sizes before rendering...

Answer (score 0):

apply `width` property to both span

```
<span style="float:left; width:50%;">This is a longer text that could potentially split into more than one line.</span>
<span style="float:right; width:50%;">Force this text into one line.</span>
```

or see here http://jsfiddle.net/pE2c8/4/, you can understand.

Comment: This would imply to calculate the width and set it prior to rendering (not good as it can only be a guess) or with Javascript wich I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of doing this is to switch the 2 spans around in your HTML. Add width 100% to the span that should break up, and float right to the full width span.

HTML

```
<html>
    <div>
         <span style="float:right;">Force this text into one line.asdsadsadasdsasadsad asd</span>
        <span style="width:100%;">This is a longer text that could potentially split into more than one line. </span>

    </div>
</html>
```

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/pE2c8/6/

Comment: I like this, but then everything after the first line of the `width: 100%` span will be full-width, which I don't think is what @Martin intended.

Comment: @Elise Yeah you are prob right, it's not really mentioned in the question tho

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get away with achieving this without specifying at least *some* kind of width properties for your two spans, as you need some way of saying where the first container should break its lines. In this case you knowing that the second container won't take up more than about 30% might be useful.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pE2c8/7/)**

By using `max-width`:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    max-width: 70%;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    max-width: 30%;
    /* Can add the following for good measure
       (will keep on one line even if over 30% wide
       and hides the excess) */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This one does the trick, but not 100% as it would be the same as fixing widths 70-30. What I really need is that if the right span takes 15%, the left one takes 85%... I am trying to calculate the widths before rendering and fix them, but it's not that clean...